# How to change dtaidistance plot size after clustering?

Tags: python, plot, hierarchical-clustering

I seem to be unable to change the output plot size using the *dtaidistance* package in Python/PyCharm. There seems to be no "figsize" parameter or something the like in the *model.plot* function and wrapping the whole plot in SciPy style like described below leads to an empty plot [Code adapted from https://pydigger.com/pypi/dtaidistance]:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from dtaidistance import dtw, clustering
import numpy as np

# demo data matrix:
series = np.matrix([
     [0., 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
     [0., 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [1., 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
     [0., 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
     [0., 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [1., 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1]])

# Custom Hierarchical clustering
model1 = clustering.Hierarchical(dtw.distance_matrix_fast, {})
# Augment Hierarchical object to keep track of the full tree
model2 = clustering.HierarchicalTree(model1)

# Fit Model:
cluster_idx = model2.fit(series=series)

# create plot:
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(14, 10))
tree = model2.plot("mytree.png")
plt.show()
```

In the current state, the plot is being saved as *mytree.png*, but in a very low resolution. This low resolution plot can be shown via

```
import matplotlib.image as mpimg

img = mpimg.imread("mytree.png")
imgplot = plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()
```

but I need a much higher resolution than the one provided...

Answer (score 1):

I just found the solution. Create a subplots figure and assign the correct axis to the model.plot function while removing the specified name (no saving needed):

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(ncols=2, nrows=1, figsize=(12, 8))  # attention: 2 columns needed!
tree_plot = model2.plot(axes=ax)
plt.show()
```

I guess this was a matplotlib-specific problem after all...